# How can I add a style tag in the header with jade/pug?

Tags: pug

I want something like this:

```
html
  head
    style(type="text/css")
      table {
        width: 100%
      }
  body
    table
```

But can't find the right incantation. This results in an "unexpected text" error. I tried escaping the css with a |, to no avail; and the best I've achieved so far is getting a table tag rendered in the header :(

Is it possible to do this with jade/pug?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, you can add arbitrary text to any tag by suffixing it with a dot:

```
style(type="text/css").
  table {
    width: 100%
  }
```

In the documentation: https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#recommended-solutions

Comment: great, thanks! is that documented anywhere? (although now I know to look for it, I can see it right there in the example on the front page)